# What word should I fill in the dotted line to make these 2 actions equivalent, "to put his head through the ring" and "to put the ring … his head"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

We say "**to put his head through the ring**" **(1)**, and what prepositions should we fill in the dotted line to make this phrase "**to put the ring … his head**" equivalent to the **(1)**.?

"**to put the ring through his head**" or "**to put the ring over his head**"?

Comment: I would say "around his head"

Comment: What is the context for this question?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, in a circus, some performers put their heads through the fire rings

Comment: @Tom Then I would agree with Cardinal's answer.

Comment: I would suggest that "over" might be a more idiomatically natural option, despite the fact that it looks as though that means the ring would end up above the head.